# Understanding the definition of $G$-gerbe

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, stacks, gerbes

In [Introduction to Differentiable Stacks](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gregory.ginot/papers/DiffStacksIGG2013.pdf) Gregory Ginot defines a $G$-gerbe as the following.

> Let $G$ be a Lie group. A $G$-gerbe over a stack $\mathcal{C}$ is a gerbe over stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ which locally is isomorphic to $[pt/G]\times \mathcal{C}$.

I am not able to understand what is locally isomorphic here.

Can some one help to clarify this.

I am trying to make sense of this by imitating what does it mean to say principal $S^1$ bundle over a manifold. It means a  smooth map $P\rightarrow M$ that locally looks like product i.e., there exists an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$ with trivializations $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\rightarrow U_\alpha\times S^1$. One can see this $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ as pull back of inclusion $U_\alpha\rightarrow U$ along $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ .

If we imitatie, by locally isomorphic we mean, I think it means there exists an atlas (open cover in above sense) $\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that the fiber product $\mathcal{D}\times_{\mathcal{C}}\underline{X}$ (pull back $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ in above sense) is some how related to $[pt/G]\times \mathcal{C}$.

In [Differentiable Stacks and Gerbes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605694.pdf)  Kai Behrend and Ping Xu defines an $S^1$-gerbe as the following.

> An $S^1$-gerbe over $\mathfrak{X}$ is a gerbe $\mathfrak{R}\rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ which is locally isomorphic to $BS^1\times \mathfrak{X}$ and is endowed with a trivialization of its band (the $2$-sheeted covering $\underline{Band}(\mathfrak{R})\rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$).

In this also there was not much explanation of what is locally isomorphic to.

Any comments on definition of Band is welcome.

In [Some notes on Differentiable stacks](https://www.uni-due.de/~hm0002/stacks.pdf) J. Heinloth defines a $G$-gerbe as the following.

> A gerbe $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is called an $S^1$-gerbe if there is an atlas $\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and a section $s:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ such that there is an isomorphism $(X\times_{\mathcal{D}}X)\times_{X\times_{\mathcal{C}}X}X\cong S^1\times X$ "as a family of groups over $X$" with some other conditions.

By specifying "as a family of groups on $X$" I think he want  to see $S^1\times X$ as not just like a manifold but see $S^1$ as a Lie group and $X$ as a manifold separately I mean the stack associated to $S^1\times X$ as $BS^1\times \underline{X}$ and not $\underline{S^1\times X}$. This seems compatible with what Gregory says i.e., locally isomorphic to $[pt/G]\times \mathcal{C}$. Here $G=S^1$ and $[pr/G]\times \mathcal{C}$ is $[pt/S^1]\times \mathcal{C}$ i.e., $BS^1\times \mathcal{C}$.

Can some one help to clarify this.

Comment: It should be locally _equivalent_, not isomorphic, since gerbes are categories. It's just an abuse of terminology though. If you can get your hands on Breen's monograph in the Asterisque series (_On the classification of 2-gerbes and 2-stacks_, Astérisque **225** (1994)), then there's a nice treatment of ordinary gerbes as well (and ignore the 2-gerbe stuff). Otherwise his less detailed but newer notes https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611317 would suffice.

Comment: Say $C$ and $D$ are CFG over the same base category $S$, and $D$ is also a CFG over $C$. I would interpret the condition you mention as saying: $D$ and $[pt/G]\times C$ have to be locally (*over* $C$, not locally over $S$) isomorphic (in the sense of equivalent as CFG) stacks. This just means there's an atlas $X\to C$ of $C$ such that the fibered products $D\times_C X$ and $([pt/G]\times C)\times_C X = [pt/G]\times X$ are isomorphic as stacks (i.e. equivalent as CFG) over $X$ (Which is the same -I'd say but I'm not sure- as saying they are just isomorphic as stacks over $S$).

Comment: @Qfwfq Oh.. ok ok. I am happy that what you are saying intersects non triviallly with what I said (existence of an atlas atleast :D)... so, you are saying it is not that $\mathcal{D}\times_{\mathcal{C}}X$ is same as that of $[pt/G]\times \mathcal{C}$ but it is same as that of  $[pt/G]\times \mathcal{C}\times_{\mathcal{C}}X=[pt/G]\times X$... I think I understand what you said,,, do you have any reference other than what is suggested by David Roberts above..

Comment: @DavidRoberts I have notes on 1-gerbes and 2-gerbes.. I will read that.. it only discusses $G$-gerbe over a manifold $X$ and $G$ for them is not just a group but a bundle of groups over $X$... I will read that section and ask here (after spending some 15 hours) if I did not understand something.. Thank you.

Comment: @Qfwfq i was just trying to imitate open cover with atlas...I don’t know what is good enough here,, atlas or representable or any random map of stacks from $X$... I will think... I will see that stacks project also...

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was not correct. You don't have triviality of the pulled-back thing under *every* (representable) map, not even *every* representable map that belongs to the topology on $S$. You have *local* triviality for every repres map, that is: up to taking a further pullback along a cover (in your topology).

Comment: @Qfwfq I am getting confused.. may be some thing which is not correct I can understand quickly and something which is correct I need some time :D Can you kindly say in little more detailed way..

Comment: What I said in my (deleted) comment would have implied for example that if $C$ is a scheme (/space/etc...), every gerbe $D$ over $C$ was trivial, i.e. isomorphic to $BG\times C$, which is clearly wrong. Instead it works this way: take any map $T\to C$ and consider the pullback $D_T:=D\times_C T$; this is *not* $BG\times T$ in general, *but* if you take a suitable cover $U\to T$, then the further pullback $D_U:=D_T\times_T U$ will be a trivial $G$-gerbe, i.e. isom. to $BG\times U$.

Comment: @Qfwfq Isn't it the case that $D\times_C T\times_ T U$ is same as $D\times_C U$?

Comment: Yep it's the same

Comment: Then I am not sure why are you specifying to consider $T\rightarrow C$ and then a cover $U\rightarrow T$.. We can simply say there exists a (atlas??) $U\rightarrow C$ such that $D\times_C U$ is the stack $BG\times U$.. @Qfwfq Am I misunderstanding something here..

Comment: Yes, if an atlas exists. But I think the general definition, with arbitrary (not even representable) maps $T\to C$ and then a suitable *cover* $U\to T$, makes sense even when an atlas does not exist. [The composite $U\to C$ may not even be representable, e.g. if the diagonal of C is not representable (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57296/exactly-how-is-the-diagonal-is-representable-used-for-algebraic-stacks), and if representable may not be étale/etc]. The property of having an atlas is not needed for the definition of gerbe.

Comment: @Qfwfq Ok Ok.. I got it :) Thanks Thanks... I am reading from Kai Behrend and Ping Xu's paper Differentiable gerbes and stacks.. They use the notion  of Band of a gerbe to talk about $S^1$ gerbe... Can you suggest some papers/recent PhD thesis which discusses Band of a Gerbe and all that??

Comment: Idk, maybe the monograph by L. Breen suggested in the comment by David Roberts has that concept explained too?

Comment: @Qfwfq They only discuss $G$-gerbe over a space. For them, $G$ is not just a group but a bundle of groups on $X$ i.e., a map $G\rightarrow X$ such that fibres $G_x$ are groups with some compatibility... They talk about what are called $G$-torsors... This gives a gerbe $\text{Tors}(G)$ over $X$... A gerbe $\mathcal{P}$ on $X$ is said to be a $G$-gerbe if there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ and objects $x_i\in \mathcal{P}(U_i)$ such that the bundle of groups $G_i=\text{Aut}_{\mathcal{P}(U_i)}(x_i)$ is such that $G_i\cong G|_{U_i}$ for all $i$..[continuation]

Comment: @Qfwfq Article is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611317.pdf They discuss this in page $9$... I am trying to make sense of this and trying to see how this changes when $X$ is replaced by a stack i.e., how should a $G$-gerbe should be defined in the sense of $\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is a stack...

Answer (score 1):

In [Brauer Groups and Quotient stacks](https://www.math.brown.edu/~bhassett/papers/brauer/brauer.amj.pdf), they define $G$-gerbe as follows.

Set up : Fix a Noeth. scheme $X$. Let $G$ be a group scheme (flat, separated and of finite type) over $X$.

> A $G$-gerbe over $X$ is a morphism $F\rightarrow X$, with $F$ an algebraic stack, such that there exists a faithfully flat map, locally of finite presentation, $X'\rightarrow X$ such that $F\times_XX'\cong BG\times_XX'$.

As $G$ is a group scheme over $X$, there is an obvious morphism $BG\rightarrow X$. So, we can then talk about the product $BG\times_XX'$. This may not be the case in case of differential geometric set up.

---

A morphism of stacks $F:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is a $G$-gerbe, If it is a gerbe over stack in the usual sense and, I think what they mean is, there exists an atlas $p:\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that the pullback $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{C}}\mathcal{D}$ is isomorphic to the stack $BG\times_{\text{Man}}\underline{X}$.

---

I also think there should be something like an action map $BG\times_{\text {Man}}\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ which should be behaving like Lie group action on a manifold $P\times G\rightarrow P$ in case of Principal $G$ bundle.

Comment: BG is not grouplike if G is not abelian, so won't act like you suggest in that case. It's more like a fibre bundle than a principal bundle...

Comment: I am ok if it is like a fiber bundle than a principal bundle where there is no expected action of fibere on top space.... But, I am not able to relate the justificication.. Usually, when we start with a Lie group, we talk about principal group bundles, which comes with an action, I was expecting similar thing here, something like a principal G bundle, you are saying we are not expecting a principal bundle like behaviour but we are expecting a fiber bundle like behaviour... @DavidRoberts

Comment: Excluding the action map, should the rest be taken as definition for G-gerbe? @DavidRoberts

Comment: The definition of gerbe is what it is, and a $G$-gerbe is one where all the automorphism groups of the objects are abstractly isomorphic to $G$. Together with the definition of gerbe, this implies 'locally equivalent to the classifying stack of $G$'.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Is “local equivalence to the classifying stack” same as “existence of atlas $\underline{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that $\underline{X}\times_{\mathcal{C}}\mathcal{D}\cong BG\times_{\text{Man}}\underline{X}$”?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: sorry, no. I have nothing to add.

Comment: Ok :) thanks ...